# What is the area of a spherical non-geodetic triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, quaternions, spherical-coordinates, spherical-trigonometry

The question relates to a general polygon, but I guess a single triangle is a reasonable reduction.

I can formulate the problem as follows: Given three points $v_1,v_2,v_3$ on the unit sphere, and three quaternions $q_{12}, q_{23}, q_{31}$ that transform the respective points to each other, what is the *signed* area enclosed by the interpolated curve? Assume it is supposed to be right-handed positive for an outward normal to the sphere.

The transformations are not necessarily geodetic (great circles), which mean we don't have that $q_{ij}=v_i^{-1}v_j$ (assuming $v$ as imaginary quaternions). This rules out the simple Girard formula for spherical excess (or does it?).

Comment: Do you connect the vertices by interpolating the quaternions?

Comment: A quaternion $q_{ij}$ defines a curve $v_{ij}(t), t \in [0,1]$ by an interpolation function: $v_{ij}(t)=q_{ij}^{-1}(t)v_iq_{ij}$, where $q_{ij}(t)=(q_{ij})^t$.

Comment: Why do you need quaternions if you have the three points $v_1$, etc.?

Comment: Because there is an extra degree of freedom, as these are not shortest rotations/great circles. See last paragraph.

Comment: As area on the sphere is proportional to [angle excess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_excess), I'd guess one should be able to integrate the angle excess along each edge, then add the angle excess at each of the corners.

Comment: Could you be more specific? you mean something along the lines of the curvature of the triangle?

Comment: If you don't have geodesics bounding the edges, they you cannot call it a triangle.  Spherical triangles are bounded by geodesics (i.e. great circles).  A transform which takes one point to another is path independent.  Regardless of the path taken a rotation from $v_1$ to $v_2$ is going to be the same.

Comment: Ok, it's not a "triangle" per se, as in defined by vertices and nothing else, but the problem is still well-formulated.